# Ajax post to spring mvc controller which refresh datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, datatables

I am trying to create a storage of metadata which searches data using a web gui. The application is built using ajax and datatables within my spring application.

## BACKGROUND:

The search area is as shown below:

```
====================================================================
=  Start Date           =   Table                      search[  ]  =                  
=  ___________________  =   -------------------------------------  =         
= |2012-12-11 09:24:03| =   -                                   -  = 
=                       =   -                                   -  =
=  Stop Date            =   -                                   -  =                                      
=  ___________________  =   -                                   -  =
= |2012-12-11 09:24:40| =   -                                   -  =
=                       =   -                                   -  =       
=  Duration >           =   -                                   -  =                                      
=  ___________________  =   -                                   -  =
= |     00:4:40       | =   -                                   -  =
=                       =   -                                   -  =
=  ___________________  =   -                                   -  =
= |     Search        | =   -------------------------------------  =
=                       =   showing 1 of 2000 entries     Page 1   =
====================================================================
```

**Search.js**

```
var table;
var searchpage = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[3].href;

searchRecording=function() 
{
    var startDate = $('#startDate').data('date');
    var stopDate = $('#stopDate').data('date');
    var duration = $('#duration').data('date');

    $.ajax({
        "type": 'POST',
        "url": searchpage,
        "data": JSON.stringify({
            "startDate": startDate,
            "stopDate": stopDate,
            "duration": duration,
        }),
         success : function(response) {  
              alert(response);   
             },  
             error : function(e) {  
              alert('Error: ' + e);   
             },  
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}

window.searchBtn.onclick = function() 
{
    return function() 
    {
        searchRecording();
    }
}();

var searchBtn = document.getElementById("searchBtn");

table = $('#table').DataTable({

        "bProcesing" : true,
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "bLenthChange" : false,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 15, 20, 25, 50], [10, 15, 20, 25, 50]],
        "iDisplayLength" : 10,
        "iDisplayStart": 0,
        "sEcho":1,
        "sAjaxSource":searchpage,
        "fnServerData": function(searchpage, aoData, fnCallback) 
        {
                        $.ajax({
                         "dataType" : 'json',
                         "type" : "POST",
                         "url" : searchpage,
                         "data" : aoData,
                         "success" : fnCallback
                        });
                    },  
        "columns": [
                    { data: "id" },
                    { ....Other Columns.... } ,
                   ]

    });
```

**SearchController.java (Controller)**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchpage", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String showRecordings(
            @RequestParam (required=true) int sEcho,   
            @RequestParam (required=true) int iDisplayStart,   
            @RequestParam (required=true) int iDisplayLength    
            ) 
    {

        System.out.print(sEcho+" ");
        System.out.print(iDisplayStart+" ");
        System.out.println(iDisplayLength+" ");


        //String startDate = (String) data.get("startDate");
        //String stopDate = (String) data.get("stopDate");
        //String duration = (String) data.get("duration");


        DataTablesTO<Rec> dt = new DataTablesTO<Rec>();

        List<Rec> recs = recordingsService.getAllRecs(iDisplayStart, iDisplayLength);
        Long size = recordingsService.getAllRecsSize();
        dt.setAaData(recs);                      // This is the dataset reponse to client
        dt.setiTotalDisplayRecords(size.intValue()); // the total data in  db for datatables to calculate page no. and position
        dt.setiTotalRecords(size.intValue());        // the total data in db for datatables to calculate page  no.
        dt.setsEcho(sEcho);

        return toJson(dt);
    }

    private String toJson(DataTablesTO<?> dt) 
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try 
        {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(dt);
        } 
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Search.jsp**

The form contains bootstrap datetimepickers and the button that submit the form is

```
<button id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
```

## QUESTION:

I would be gratefult if could help me to understand how should I connect the form to the table. For instance, If I press the search button the start date and stop date are sent to the controller the controller search for the data and return the result to the table which is automatically refreshed using ajax

- Is my approach right?
- Are there any redundant parts in my code?
- How should I pass dates values to the controller?
- How should I pass datatable init values when I press the search button?

At the moment I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required int parameter 'sEcho' is not present
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your approach for sending the required data from the client side and fetching that data from the server side is different.
You are sending one object from client side but expecting 3 on the server side.
client side:

```
"data" : aoData,
```

Server side:

```
@RequestParam (required=true) int sEcho,   
@RequestParam (required=true) int iDisplayStart,   
@RequestParam (required=true) int iDisplayLength
```

One approach is, on the server side get the data in a DTO (data transfer object), which is nothing but an object containing multiple fields corresponding to the multiple data you are sending.
So get all the data in that custom abject and get individual ones from that one.

currently you are sending one object but you are mandatory expecting 3, the first one amongst which is a number. hence the error.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the server side but I do not fully get the javascript side. How can I put multiple variables like `sEcho`, `iDisplayStart`, `iDisplayLength` in the aoData object.

Comment: How can I trigger "fnServerData" to be updated with an ajax request? I created a `searchRecording` function to send an ajax request but still I do not get the full picture

Comment: make a json in your javascript code. the properties should be the ones you want to send. make a java object with the same structure and property names in the serverside code and tell your method to expect that type of data from the client side